# Multiple sed -e command usage in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to understand the below command. Looked many tutorials and references. Can anyone help What actually it does.

```
 sed -e '$d' -e '1,1d' File1 >File2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$d` wil delete the last line

To delete lines between `n` and `m` use `n,md`. ie. `1,1d` is same as `1d`, which deletes the first line

So `sed -e '$d' -e '1,1d' File1 >File2` will remove first and last line from `File1` and send to `file2`